# create namespace operation not permitted?

Tags: go, namespaces

I' am learning about Linux Namespace and I tried to create a UTS Namespace via golang. here is my code

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("sh")
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        Cloneflags: syscall.CLONE_NEWUTS,
    }
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

When I executed `go run uts.go`, I got the error `fork/exec /bin/sh: operation not permitted`.My OS is `Ubuntu 18.04.3`, Linux Kerenl version is `5.0.0-32-generic`.

Comment: From the docs: "Only a privileged process (CAP_SYS_ADMIN) can employ CLONE_NEWUTS". Does your process have `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`?

Comment: @JimB no, thks, I know the reason.

Answer (score 2):

Build the program instead and then run the executable file as sudo.

go build uts.go

sudo ./uts

Answer (score 1):

From the [Linux doc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html)
**CLONE_NEWUTS (since Linux 2.6.19)**
 uname(2); among these, the domain name and the hostname can be
              modified by setdomainname(2) and sethostname(2), respectively.
              Changes made to the identifiers in a UTS namespace are visible
              to all other processes in the same namespace, but are not
              visible to processes in other UTS namespaces.

**Only a privileged process (CAP_SYS_ADMIN) can employ
          CLONE_NEWUTS.**